# Rails: Using Controller as a Model Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model that is called "controller". I checked the rails reserved terms list and it does not show "controller" as a word not to be used.

The model works fine but when I use the model in a view, the view does not submit the controller attribute back to the controller.

Any idea if "controller" is in fact a reserved word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `controller` is reserved in RoR. Even you can use it like this in your views:

```
#to get controller name:
<%= controller.controller_name %>


#to get action name, it is the method:
<%= controller.action_name %>
```

Comment: Thank you. That explains the behavior.